# Reading an entire directory of .pdb files using BioPython

Tags: python, biopython, pdb

I was recently tasked to write a program in python to find atoms within 2 angstroms distance from every metal in a protein from a .pdb (Protein Data Bank). This is the script I wrote for it.

```
from Bio.PDB import *
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=True)

def print_coordinates(list):
    neighborList = list
    for y in neighborList:
        print "     ", y.get_coord()

structure_id = '5m6n'
fileName = '5m6n.pdb'
structure = parser.get_structure(structure_id, fileName)

atomList = Selection.unfold_entities(structure, 'A')

ns = NeighborSearch(atomList)

for x in structure.get_atoms():
    if x.name == 'ZN' or x.name == 'FE' or x.name == 'CU' or x.name == 'MG' or x.name == 'CA' or x.name == 'MN':
        center = x.get_coord()
        neighbors = ns.search(center,2.0)
        neighborList = Selection.unfold_entities(neighbors, 'A')

        print x.get_id(), ': ', neighborList
        print_coordinates(neighborList)
    else:
        continue
```

But this is only for a single .pdb file, I would like to be able to read an entire directory of them. Since I've only been using Java until now, I am not entirely sure how I would be able to do this in Python 2.7. An idea I have is that I would put the script in a try catch statement and in it, a while loop, then throw an exception when it reaches the end, but that's how I would've done in Java, not sure how I would do it in Python. So I would love to hear any idea or sample code anyone might have.

Comment: You will probably want to look at the `os` module, particularly [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

Comment: As an aside, you can also replace your long list of `or` statements with `if x.name in ('ZN', 'FE', 'CU', 'MG', 'CA', 'MN')`

Comment: @asongtoruin Thanks for that suggestion, and I'll look into the module you mentioned.

Comment: Another small note: naming a variable (`list`) like a type will cause troubles at some point. Just use `neighborList` as the function parameter, then you can also skip the first line in your function.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Yea I thought about it, it's just kind of a habit, mostly because I feel kind of insecure that Python doesn't let you define the type of each variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some redundancies in your code, for instance this does the same:

```
from Bio.PDB import *
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=True)

def print_coordinates(neighborList):
    for y in neighborList:
        print "     ", y.get_coord()

structure_id = '5m6n'
fileName = '5m6n.pdb'
structure = parser.get_structure(structure_id, fileName)
metals = ['ZN', 'FE', 'CU', 'MG', 'CA', 'MN']

atomList = [atom for atom in structure.get_atoms() if atom.name in metals]
ns = NeighborSearch(Selection.unfold_entities(structure, 'A'))

for atom in atomList:
    neighbors = ns.search(atom.coord, 2)
    print("{0}: {1}").format(atom.name, neighbors)
    print_coordinates(neighborList)
```

To answer your question, you can get a list of all your pdb files using the `glob` module and nest your code on a `for` loop iterating over all files. Supposing your pdb files are at `/home/pdb_files/`:

```
from Bio.PDB import *
from glob import glob
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=True)
pdb_files = glob('/home/pdb_files/*')

def print_coordinates(neighborList):
    for y in neighborList:
        print "     ", y.get_coord()

for fileName in pdb_files:
     structure_id = fileName.rsplit('/', 1)[1][:-4]
     structure = parser.get_structure(structure_id, fileName)
     # The rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you for this, really helped not only with my problem, but also my  transition into python. Thanks again!